# MVC Bootstrap Tabs w/Partial Views & Multiple Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble with setting up a view with bootstrap tabs, and each tab will have a partial view containing a grid view along with some other options.

I made this view model to contain models of both grids to pass:

```
public class GridModel
{
    public List<GridRecurringTemplate> GridRecurringTemplates { get; set; }
    public List<GridSpecialTemplate> GridSpecialTemplates { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the index containing the tabs  I load with the GridModel:

```
@model Business.ViewModels.GridModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
}


<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tabpanel">
    <li class="active"><a href="#recurring" data-toggle="tab">Recurring</a>              </li>
    <li><a href="#special" data-toggle="tab">Special</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabContent" class="tab-content">

    @* Recurring Tab*@
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="recurring">
        @Html.Partial("_RecurringTab", Model.GridRecurringTemplates)
    </div>

    @* Special Tab*@
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="special">
        @Html.Partial("_SpecialTab", Model.GridSpecialTemplates)
    </div>

</div>
```

What am I adding to the top of the view for each partial view?  And am I handling the `@Html.Partial` view correctly above by passing `Model.GridRecurringTemplates` or `Model.GridSpecialTemplates` ?

I see references to Ajax when looking for answers about tabs with multiple models and views, but I am new to MVC and web all together, so I haven't used it before.

Here is my controller passing the viewmodel to the index

```
    // GET: ScheduleTemplate
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new GridModel();
        return View(model); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To the top of each partial View You should add:

`@model List<Business.ViewModels.GridRecurringTemplate>` - For `_RecurringTab`

`@model List<Business.ViewModels.GridSpecialTemplate>` - For `_SpecialTab`

It follows from your `ViewModel`.

You find refferences to Ajax. You may need this if you want to load your partial View when certain tab opens. Then you should use ajax call on tab selected event.

But now i see that you pass full model to your Main View and just render then on your partial (This is one shot from server).

Comment: @ teo van kot  So I continue to pass in the viewmodel at the @Html.Partial("_RecurringTab", Model.GridRecurringTemplates), then in the partial view I call to the model directly ? Business.ViewModels.GridRecurringTemplate.   Is that right?

Comment: What do you mean by call? It all happeneds on server and on your partial you already have model as list of your passed model

Comment: I guess what I am thinking is if you pass the viewmodel (@model Business.ViewModels.GirdModel) to the main view where the partials are getting called.  Then on the partial wouldn't the model passed in need to be something like @model List<Business.ViewModels.GridModel.GridRecurringTemplate>?  But I can't seem to make that work

Comment: Yes, it whould, as i mension. If this isn't work i gess we need more info what exactly wrong

Comment: I get this exception when trying to load the index which as the gridmodel:  {"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Business.ViewModels.GridModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Business.ViewModels.GridRecurringTemplate]'."}    I had to use IEnumerable instead of List on the partial views model.  This is why I am having trouble passing in multiple views to use in multiple partial views

Comment: i can't see dictionary here. It's arror either on your Partial View or on controller.